# How can I use a csv list to filter on a column in Excel

Tags: excel

Lets Say I have the following table formatted as a table in excel:

```
**Man** | **Email** |**Code**
Aman | aman@aman.com ! 123
Bman | bman@aman.com ! 465
Cman | cman@aman.com ! 159
Cman | cman@aman.com ! 374
Cman | cman@aman.com ! 1283
Dman | dman@aman.com ! 495
```

I want to filter on the email column by inserting a list of "cman@aman.com, bman@aman.com, eman@aman.com"
I've tried using all the different wording on it but the filter always just looks for the entirety of the pasted content in the box. I'd just like to not have to manually filter for each email. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start by converting the comma-separated list into single cells and place into one column. [Select the data... Text to columns... delimited by comma... then copy the results and transpose into a single column by using paste special option]. In my data below, that was done and placed into column E.

Then select your email header cell (B1 in my case) and click on the Advanced Filter button within Data tab.

```
    The List Range should auto-populate with the cells from column B. 

    For Criteria Range, select the values you want to search.
```

[image]

After clicking OK, you have your results:

[image]

Since rows are hidden during the filter process, you'll see that column E also has hidden rows. Therefore, maybe it's best to place column E into another tab when running this process. That should avoid possible confusion.